# c++ overload operator new delete,

Tags: c++, overloading, new-operator

Hi this is a little complicated so please let me know if any of this does not make sense, our team is writing a C++ application and we have previously had operator new overloaded. Recently I ran into this article: http://www.flipcode.com/archives/How_To_Find_Memory_Leaks.shtml about how to get debug information with our memory allocations.

All the files within the application #include one file where we have compile-time platform configurations, and within that file I added the following:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
void* operator new(size_t size, const char *filename, const char *funcname, int line);
void* operator new[](size_t size, const char *filename, const char *funcname, int line);
#define new new(__FILE__, __FUNCSIG__, __LINE__)
#endif
```

Since we only link libcmt.lib for our platform build, to use the STL I removed our old implementation of operator new which looked like:

```
// in a .cpp file:
void*
operator new(size_t size) { ... }
```

and replaced it with:

```
// in the same .cpp file as above...
#undef new
void* operator new(size_t size, const char *filename, const char *funcname, int line) { ... }
#define new new(__FILE__, __FUNCSIG__, __LINE__)
```

this works fine for compiling, but I'm getting a bunch of linker errors from libcmt.lib:

ex: libcmt.lib(malloc.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_HeapAlloc

Adding back the old implementation of operator new (without the additional parameters) allows the linker to link everything successfully.

My question: I want libcmt to see my macro (#define new new(**FILE**, **FUNCSIG**, **LINE**)) and thus when it links try and link the version I defined (with the debug macros).

How do I get this to work?? (I also tried using the property sheets within visual studio to define the macro)

Comment: I think the library won't link because it wasn't compiled with your overloaded `new` operator. Just defining an overloaded `new` in your own code won't magically make it appear in the pre-built library.

Comment: As @dreamlax said, this won't work. It's a Microsoft hack in MFC that should be taken out and shot. Writing a macro whose name is a keyword produces undefined behavior if that keyword is used after the macro is defined.

Comment: @PeteBecker I would prefer a good old-fashioned biblical stoning myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get it to work.  If this macro is defined in any file that includes a standard header, the behavior is undefined.  And of course, normal evolution of a project will lead people to define class local `operator new`, or use placement new, or any one of a number of techniques which this macro will break.  It's on about the same level as `#define while if`.  Redefining a keyword in a macro is a sure way of getting into trouble, even if you don't use the standard library.