# Why shouldn't C++ operator new/delete/variants be in header files?

Tags: c++, gcc, delete-operator, translation-unit

Can someone explain the nature of this C++ compile error? I am dabbling in/learning about overloading the global operators new, delete, and their variants. I read a [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635157/c-overload-operator-new-delete) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639676/overloading-global-operator-new-delete-in-c) [articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21997668/operator-new-and-delete-overloading-scope) [on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21997668/operator-new-and-delete-overloading-scope) [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513425/what-are-operator-new-and-operator-delete) [subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24770119/operator-delete-signature-unexpected-behavior), but I couldn't find one that seems to address this specifically.

**The Code**

`foo.h`:

```
#ifndef foo_h
#define foo_h

void* operator new(size_t);
void* operator new[](size_t);

void operator delete(void*);
void operator delete[](void*);

#endif // foo_h
```

`foo.cpp`:

```
#include <foo.h>
#include <iostream>

void* operator new(size_t size) { return NULL; }
void* operator new[](size_t size) { return NULL; }

void operator delete(void* p) { }
void operator delete[](void* p) { }
```

**The Compile Error**

```
>g++ -g -std=c++14 -I./ -c foo.cpp -o foo.o
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/ext/new_allocator.h:33:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/x86_64-pc-cygwin/bits/c++allocator.h:33,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/string:41,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/ios:42,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from foo.cpp:2:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/new:116:41: error: declaration of ‘void operator delete(void*) noexcept’ has a different exception specifier
   __attribute__((__externally_visible__));
                                         ^
In file included from foo.cpp:1:0:
./foo.h:8:6: error: from previous declaration ‘void operator delete(void*)’
 void operator delete(void* p);
      ^
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/ext/new_allocator.h:33:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/x86_64-pc-cygwin/bits/c++allocator.h:33,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/string:41,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/ios:42,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from foo.cpp:2:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/new:118:41: error: declaration of ‘void operator delete [](void*) noexcept’ has a different exception specifier
   __attribute__((__externally_visible__));
                                         ^
In file included from foo.cpp:1:0:
./foo.h:9:6: error: from previous declaration ‘void operator delete [](void*)’
 void operator delete[](void* p);
      ^
```

Some oddities about this issue that I think are relevant:

- If I comment out `#include <iostream>` in `foo.cpp`, compilation succeeds
- If I comment out the function declarations in `foo.h`, and only keep their definitions, in `foo.cpp` (and also keeping `#include <iostream>`), compilation succeeds.

I have some vague suspicions; perhaps answerers will confirm by way of their answers:

- The error makes mention of an `exception specifier` so I thought maybe by overriding any of these operators, I am obliged to override the entire suite of their siblings. However, adding `operator delete(void*, const std::nothrow_t&)` declaration and definition did not change the compile error. I also don't think it should be true that overriding any of these operators obliges the coder to implement all of them, but am I mistaken on that?
- I read an article outside of StackOverflow mentioning that these operators must only be included in one "translation unit" and therefore should not be in header files. I don't understand what a translation unit is, and that article did not explain what it is. If that is related to this problem, please explain what a "translation unit" is and why that necessitates exclusion of function declarations from a header file - this seems contrary to all my prior C++ coding experience.

Thank you for any insight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is due to differences in the following declarations.

The library declares the `operator delete` functions as:

```
void operator delete(void*) noexcept;
void operator delete [](void*) noexcept;
```

while you declare them as:

```
void operator delete(void*);
void operator delete [](void*);
```

Instead of declaring them in your .h file, you should use

```
#include <new>
```

Lookup section **18.6 Dynamic memory management** of the C++11 standard if you have access to it for more information on the subject.

A translation unit is usually a .cpp file. Further reading: [What is a "translation unit" in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106149/what-is-a-translation-unit-in-c).

Comment: Your answer made me realize the compiler error was actually telling me exactly what the problem was. My bad for not scrutinizing it more, but thank you; your answer helped me bridge the gap.

Comment: It's strange, because I'm not able to reproduce that same error, and I copied the exact same code, which was posted in the question. If that's really the problem, why am not I getting the error? btw, I'm using VS 2015.

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad, I don't know why you are not getting any error. It's worth searching for.

Comment: @MuhammedAhmad, I would suspect the difference you see is because of your compiler (cl.exe?). There are definitely subtle differences in compiler (and linkers) behavior (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159681/g-cygwin-linux-or-version-discrepancy for example). Unfortunately I don't have VS 2015 to cross-verify, but R Sahu seems to have been able to verify my observation.